# Calculating total returns from a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, stock

this is my first post here, I hope you will understand what troubles me.

So, I have a DataFrame that contains prices for some 1200 companies for each day, beginning in 2010. Now I want to calculate the total return for each one. My DataFrame is indexed by date. I could use the
`df.iloc[-1]/df.iloc[0]` method, but some companies started trading publicly at a later date, so I can't get the results for those companies, as they are divided by a NaN value. I've tried by creating a list which contains the first valid indexes for every stock(column), then when I try to calculate the total returns, I get - the wrong result!
I've tried a classic for loop:

```
for l in list:
   returns = df.iloc[-1]/df.iloc[l]
```

For instance, last price of one stock was around $16, and first data I have is $1.5, which would be over 10 times return, yet my result is only about 1.1! I would also like to add that the aforementioned list includes first valid indexes for Date aswell, and it is in the first position.

Can somebody please help me? Thank you very much

Comment: Can you please provide the dataframe sample.

Comment: Please have a look here to help you improve the question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . It is almost impossible for us to answer your question in he current form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many ways you can go about this actually. But I do recommend you brush up on your python skills with basic examples before you get into more complicated examples.

If you want to do it your way, you can do it like this:

```py
returns = {}
for stock_name in df.columns:
    returns[stock_name] = df[stock_name].dropna().iloc[-1] / df[stock_name].dropna().iloc[0]
```

A more pythonic way would be to do it in a vectorized form, like this:

```py
returns = ((1 + data.ffill().pct_change())
            .cumprod()
            .iloc[-1])
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that did it!